# Build error in VS 2010

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

I am getting this error in my application

```
Error   1   Unable to copy file "D:\myproj\bin\Debug\myproj.dll" to "bin\Debug\myproj.dll". The process cannot access the file 'bin\Debug\myproj.dll' because it is being used by another process.
```

How to fix it

Answer (score 2):

Your project dll is being used by another process.  Either you ran your application and it didn't fully shut down (check the task manager) or some other program is trying to consume the dll in the d:\myproj\bin\debug\myproj.dll

For example, in the olden days, if you used a .Net dll in a VB6 app, and pointed to the debug dll, it would grab on to that and you'd have to shut down VB6 to free the dll.

I suspect you'll have to do something similar.

Start by checking task manager and making sure your app isn't still running.
Then close down any other apps that have a reference to your dll
If neither of those two work, close down studio and restart it

Comment: No, It is not being used. I just used Debug-> attach to process and trying to debug windows service

Comment: @DotnetSparrow: if VS tells you the DLL is used by another process, you can be sure, it is! If you don't believe, get a copy of Process Explorer here and check by yourself: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653%28l=en-us%29

Comment: @Doc and  @Taylor: How can I release it

Comment: @DotnetSparrow: Read the last sentence of taylonr's post and do exactly what he wrote! :-0

Comment: When you restarted VS2010, are you sure devenv.exe closed down entirely?  That is, did you watch it disappear from taskmanager?  If not, it's entirely possible it didn't completely close and you still held a reference.

Comment: @DotnetSparrow: if you don't know which process has a reference to you DLL, use the (free!) Process Explorer, as I wrote above. That tool has a "Find" feature where you just have to enter the DLL name.